# Simple Java web Spring MVC project, page not found,

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to run simple java web project, but it shows 404 not found. 
Here is my code.

Controller 
    package controller;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String show() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

dispetcher servlet .xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you also post your view ?

Comment: @EmreAcar is it important?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caching issue with Eclipse.
Clear cache it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error info is usually something you write wrong, check your URL , such as the port , or whether you have started your Tomcat.

generally, some resources are not found.